# How can "unsettling" be interpreted here?

Tags: word-meaning

There have been a number of memorable villains in the Breaking Bad universe, but perhaps none are as unsettling as Todd. Can unsettling mean here violent or rigorous?

Comment: Did you check in a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unsettling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unsettling* is like *unnerving* or *disquieting*.  Unsettling things disrupt your sense of peace or safety.  They *rattle your nerves*.  They bother you.